# Straightforward way to place text on a specific location in an image?

Tags: java, android, layout, textview, imageview

[Overhead schematic of Docks map in Modern Warfare](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Omc1N.png)

[Overhead schematic of Docks with one callout name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FIG1a.png)

I'm creating an app that will display names - "callouts" - for various specific areas of each map in the video game Modern Warfare. I want to be able to place the text (or a placeholder) in the same location, regardless of scale, transformations, etc. Is there a way to do this besides getting the (x,y) coordinates of each location in an image editor, then using those coordinates in my layout? That method seems extremely tedious because there's 10 - 20 callouts per map, and approximately 20 maps! I also want to avoid adding the text graphically so that I can change it as necessary in Android Studio.

If I place TextViews visually in the [Design] tab in Android Studio, will they stay in the same position relative to the background ImageView, regardless of scaling, transforms, etc.? Please advise, and I'll be happy to clarify if necessary. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found the solution I'm looking for, folks:

- Within a ConstraintLayout, have an ImageView to hold the map graphic, and TextViews for each callout label.
- Constrain each TextView to the Start, End, Top, and Bottom of the ImageView.
- Drag the TextViews to the desired location in the [Design] tab of the layout editor. This will automatically adjust the Horizontal and Vertical Bias, which is essentially a percentage of the parent's width and height, relative to the left and top of the parent.

In my preliminary testing, this seems to preserve the location of each callout label relative to the map, which is what I was hoping for. If anyone has anything to add, please do so!